# Setting the z-index of loader class

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, loader

I'm working in Flash AS3, AIR 3.2 for iOS SDK. I'm loading in an image, then applying a shape and textfield over this. But it seems that z-index goes weird with the loader class. At the moment, when this is run, the text and shape is applied first, and the image then gets applied on top of these even though the methods are in a different order. How do I set the shape and text to be above an image that's loaded in from the loader class?

The methods in the main method:

```
displayImage();
overlayBox();
textAnimation();
```

These are the methods:

```
public function displayImage():void {

        var imageurl:String = "image.jpg";

        myLoader = new Loader();

        var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imageurl);

        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoaderProgress);
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);

        myLoader.load(fileRequest);
    }

public function onLoaderProgress(e:ProgressEvent) {
        trace(e.bytesLoaded, e.bytesTotal); // this is where progress will be monitored
    }

public function onLoaderComplete(e:Event) {

        image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);

        var imageWidth:Number = image.width;
        var imageHeight:Number = image.height;
        var resizeWidthVar:Number;
        var resizeHeightVar:Number;

        trace("Image width: " + image.width);
        trace("Image height: " + image.height);

        if(imageWidth >= imageHeight) {
            resizeHeightVar = imageHeight/displayRes;
            trace("resizeHeightVar = " + resizeHeightVar);

            imageWidth = imageWidth/resizeHeightVar;
            imageHeight = imageHeight/resizeHeightVar;
        }
        else {
            resizeWidthVar = imageWidth/displayRes;
            trace("resizeWidthVar = " + resizeWidthVar);

            imageWidth = imageWidth/resizeWidthVar;
            imageHeight = imageHeight/resizeWidthVar;
         }

        image.width = imageWidth;
        image.height = imageHeight;

        trace("Image width: " + image.width);
        trace("Image height: " + image.height);

        image.x = xScreenPos;
        image.y = yScreenPos;

        addChild(image); // the image is now loaded, so let's add it to the display tree!
    }

public function overlayBox():void {

        var overlaySquare:Sprite = new Sprite();

        addChild(overlaySquare);

        overlaySquare.graphics.beginFill(0x00000, 0.7);
        overlaySquare.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, displayRes, displayRes);
        overlaySquare.graphics.endFill();
        overlaySquare.x = xScreenPos;
        overlaySquare.y = yScreenPos;
    }

public function textAnimation():void {

        //set text format
        textFormat.font = "Helvetica Neue Light";
        textFormat.size = 12;
        textFormat.bold = false;
        textFormat.color = 0x000000;

        // pass text format
        textOne.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;

        textOne.text = "Blah blah blah blah";
        textOne.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        textOne.x = xScreenPos;
        textOne.y = yScreenPos;

        //add to stage
        addChild(textOne);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to replace `addChild(image);` with the `addChildAt(image, 0);` another one is to add loader `addChild(loader);` and don't add image in the complete handler.

Comment: Thank you! `addChildAt(image, 0);` works. Can you explain why I have to set the image to 0 position in the display tree even when the method runs first and is added to the tree first?

Comment: you add image in the complete handler that is called asynchronously when the image loading is complete that takes some time.

Comment: Is it possible to have a statement to tell it to wait until `displayImage();` and therefore the handler to finish before it runs the next method?

Comment: If I understand you correct you want the ability to load image synchronously, as3 is a single-threaded, so it hasn't synchronous loading feature, it will stops all scripts and view scene rendering.

Comment: No, I don't want it to run synchronously. I'd want the `displayImage();` to run first, then `overlayBox();` to run only after `displayImage();` has finished loading, and so on.

Comment: So, It does called synchronously that you described. No, as3 can't do this. You simply can add the loader to the display list (as I proposed in the first comment) in the _displayImage();_ method so you will not have to care about adding image in the specific index after it loads.

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean now. Before, it was adding the image to the display list AFTER the image had loaded. I put the `addChild(myLoader);` into `displayImage();` so that it's added it to the display list BEFORE the image loads. But it means that I can't resize the image, etc, because this `image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);` can't be used for `myLoader`. How would I fix this?

Comment: Just don't create new instance of image, use the loaded one, replace _image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);_ with _image = Bitmap(e.target.content);_